# Java Anonymous Class Unique Identification

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, reflection

Lets say I want to use Command pattern that uses an Anonymous Class. In the Invoker I want to apply a cache. Something like this:

```
// command abstract class
public static abstract class ViewScopeCacheCommand<T> { 
    public abstract T invoke();
}

// innvoker
public static class ViewScopeCache<T> {
    // cache
    private Map<String,T> pageCache = null;

    public ViewScopeCache() {
        pageCache = new HashMap<String,T>();
    }
    // get from cache
    public T get(String key) {
        return pageCache.get(key);
    }
    // put to cache
    public void put(String key, T t) {
        pageCache.put(key, t);
    }
    // I want to say how to load the result of not in cache - given by command
    public T getLazy(String key, ViewScopeCacheCommand<T> command) {
        if(get(key) == null) {

            T t = command.invoke();
            pageCache.put(key, t);
        }
        return get(key);
    }
    public void invalidate() {
        pageCache.clear();
    }
    // I want to identify the cache by command
    /*
    public T getLazy(ViewScopeCacheCommand<T> command) {
        String magicKey = .. derive from command
        if(get(key) == null) {

            T t = command.invoke();
            pageCache.put(key, t);
        }
        return get(key);
    }
    */ 
}
```

Lets say I have 2 spots that use this:

```
..
Result getResult1() {
    viewScopeCache.get("key1", new ViewScopeCacheCommand<Result>() { 
       ..invoke(){ call DB SQLX }}); // does not need to be SQL, can be a service A call
}
..
Result getResult2() {
    viewScopeCache.get("key2", new ViewScopeCacheCommand<Result>() { 
       ..invoke(){ call DB SQLY}}); // does not need to be SQL, can be a service B call
}
..
```

Ok this work but can I identify the anonymous ViewScopeCacheCommand? So that the usage would simplify to this

```
..
Result getResult1() {
    viewScopeCache.get(new ViewScopeCacheCommand<Result>() { 
       ..invoke(){ call DB SQLX }}); // does not need to be SQL, can be a service A call
}
..
Result getResult2() {
    viewScopeCache.get(new ViewScopeCacheCommand<Result>() { 
       ..invoke(){ call DB SQLY}}); // does not need to be SQL, can be a service B call
}
..
```

If I had done normal class extension I could use instanceof, reflection etc.. but is there some mechanism to recognise difference between the command1 that calls SQLX and command 2 that calls SQLY
It could be Reflection based it could be code line..

The only think on my mind is annotation :(.. but that is lame..

### Some better idea/suggestion?

The question is: can I deduce the Key that could be Unique on the class level to identify a particular Command..

I could add a second method to the Command { abstract String getUniqueKey() {} } and force it to be defined.. but thats ugly :)

Comment: I'm confused. Why isn't the key determining which SQL to call?

Comment: An anonymous class isn't really anonymous at the JVM level.  It still has a unique `Class` instance associated with it.  But in general, that won't help.  What if you had `Result getResult(final int foo) { return cache.get(new Command<Result>() { invoke() { return foo + something(); } }); }`, where `foo` is a parameter?

Comment: >__I'm confused. Why isn't the key determining which SQL to call?__< This can be a method call or service call, I know what params I put to the body, this I do not need to have the key associated with param to the SQL in general

Comment: _>An anonymous class isn't really anonymous at the JVM level. It still has a unique Class instance associated with it.<_ Sure but this makes new instance of the Command each time I call it, thus I need to determine it on the class level. >The second part< The problem I am trying to solve is the to add parameter. I try to find way to, for instance, determine which of the commands was called, e.g. whether the one from Line 77 of the one from Line 88 (corresponding to new ViewScopeCacheCommand<Result>() in the getResult1/2)

Comment: Is the type `T` always `Result` for the cases you want to refactor? If not, how many different types for `T` do you need to deal with?

Comment: @user3261440: Unique *instances* aren't a problem; you'll still get a consistent result for `command.getClass()` even for an anonymous class.

Comment: T could be anything, certainly if <T> is always something else then it could work making it part of the key. Unfortunately my case have the same result type <T>

Comment: Oliver Charlesworth your answer is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oliver Charlesworth in the comments suggested that:

An anonymous class isn't really anonymous at the JVM level. It still has a unique Class instance associated with it.

He is correct the inner (anonymous) class has a unique identifier on the JVM level.

Here my test:

```
public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        loop();
    }
}

private static void loop() {
    test(new TestMe() {

        @Override
        int getKey() {
            return 100;
        }
    });
    test(new TestMe() {

        @Override
        int getKey() {
            return 200;
        }
    });
}   
public abstract static class TestMe {
    abstract int getKey();
}   
public static void test(TestMe testMe) {
    System.out.println(testMe.getClass() + " " + testMe.getKey());
}   
}
```

The output is

```
class Demo$1 100
class Demo$2 200
class Demo$1 100
class Demo$2 200
class Demo$1 100
class Demo$2 200
class Demo$1 100
class Demo$2 200
```

So the code in the question can be reduced to

```
// command abstract class
public static abstract class ViewScopeCacheCommand<T> { 
    public abstract T invoke();
}

// innvoker
public static class ViewScopeCache<T> {
   // cache
   private Map<String,T> pageCache = null;

   public ViewScopeCache() {
      pageCache = new HashMap<String,T>();
   }
   // get from cache
   public T get(String key) {
       return pageCache.get(key);
   }
   // put to cache
   public void put(String key, T t) {
       pageCache.put(key, t);
   }
   /*
   // I want to say how to load the result of not in cache - given by command
   public T getLazy(String key, ViewScopeCacheCommand<T> command) {
       if(get(key) == null) {
           T t = command.invoke();
           pageCache.put(key, t);
    }
    return get(key);
   }
   */
   public void invalidate() {
       pageCache.clear();
   }
   // I want to identify the cache by command
   /*** solution ***/
   public T getLazy(ViewScopeCacheCommand<T> command) {
       String magicKey = command.getClass().toString(); // <--- solution
       if(get(key) == null) {
           T t = command.invoke();
           pageCache.put(key, t);
       }
       return get(key);
   }
}
```

with the lazy use cases (that places the result to the cache and loads if it dies not exist in the cache):

```
..
Result getResult1() {
    viewScopeCache.get(new ViewScopeCacheCommand<Result>() { 
      ..invoke(){ call anything X }}); // does not need to be SQL, can be a service A call
}
..
Result getResult2() {
    viewScopeCache.get(new ViewScopeCacheCommand<Result>() { 
     ..invoke(){ call anything Y}}); // does not need to be SQL, can be a service B call
 }
..
```

surely I can cover also the cases where I want just the key as:

```
Result getResult3() {
    if(something empty) {
       //fetch it
       viewScopeCache.put("key3",..Z..);
    }
    viewScopeCache.get("key3");
 }
..
```

Thanks all for great discussion and solving this.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract classes can have constructors that anonymous classes can call:

```
public static abstract class ViewScopeCacheCommand<T> {
    private final String uniqueKey;

    public ViewScopeCacheCommand(String uniqueKey) {
        this.uniqueKey= uniqueKey;
    }

    public String getUniqueKey() {
        return uniqueKey;
    }

    public abstract T invoke();
}
```

The usage would be this:

```
..
Result getResult1() {
    viewScopeCache.get(new ViewScopeCacheCommand<Result>("key1") { 
        ..invoke(){ call DB SQLX }}); // does not need to be SQL, can be a service A call
}
..
Result getResult2() {
    viewScopeCache.get(new ViewScopeCacheCommand<Result>("key2") { 
        ..invoke(){ call DB SQLY}}); // does not need to be SQL, can be a service B call
}
..
```

Comment: This looks good, but would Java allow me to go further to basically reduce the need to make a "Key1" and "Key2"? Maybe it is not possible

Comment: If at all that would require reflection, but I don't know any way to get useful information. Giving the anonymous classes an identity seems like a cleaner solution though.